# How to disable Ctrl+Alt+F8?

Tags: gnome, 14.04

Is there a way to disable only key combination for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd>?

I need to use this shortcut in another application and when I trigger it, I am getting switched to the blank console (other user space). I am the only user on a machine and don't need this shortcut ever.

Ideally, I would be able to preserve keyboard shortcuts 1 to 7.

Answer (score 0):

Run the following command to find the keycode value of the desired key:

`xev`

With the small box in foreground, press the key and note the keycode value.
Then run this:

`xmodmap -e 'keycode number = NoSymbol'`

That should disable the key. To make it permanent, put this command in the System, Preferences, Sessions, Startup Programs folder, Add.

Comment: Can you try to trigger this combination of keys? I am getting sent to the blank console and I don't get any output which I can use. Here is my output: http://paste.ubuntu.com/7710784/

Comment: Take a look at this link: http://www.linuxscrew.com/2008/09/15/faq-how-to-disableremap-a-keyboard-key-in-linux/   -This provides all the keycode numbers that you can look up to disable the key

Comment: And I just sum all the number to get my key code? For example F8=74. And now I have to find values of Alt and Ctrl and sum all the numbers?

Comment: I am afraid I am not following you. Are you suggesting I disable the complete `F8` key?

Comment: Sorry, it may actually be better for you to do this in Keyboard Layout Options. If you go to that menu and click on Options, that should provide you with the option to disable the key combinations.

Comment: Disabling them individually would be a very bad idea. That would disable Ctrl and Alt globally!

Comment: Yes sorry, I just realized the mistake I made in suggesting that.